# Pontryagin square on spin and non-spin manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, characteristic-classes

The Pontryagin square, maps $x \in H^2({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ to $ \mathcal{P}(x) \in H^4({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_4)$. Precisely, 
$$
 \mathcal{P}(x)= x \cup x+ x \cup_1 2 Sq^1 x.
$$
The $\cup_1$ is a higher cup product. The $Sq^1 x=  x \cup_1 x$.

1. If I only consider the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ normal subclass as 
   $$H^4({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2) \subset H^4({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_4),$$
   then the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ generator I believe can be written as
   $$
   x \cup x =x \cup (w_2(M)+w_1(M)^2)
   $$
2. If I consider the full $\mathbb{Z}_4$ class as $H^4({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_4),$
   then the $\mathbb{Z}_4$ generator, can it be written as

   > $$
   >  \mathcal{P}(x)=  x \cup (w_2(M)+w_1(M)^2) + x \cup_1 2 Sq^1 x?
   > $$
   >   in general?
3. Therefore, on the spin-manifold $w_2(M)=w_1(M)=0$, or the Pin$^-$-manifold, the $ (w_2(M)+w_1(M)^2)=0$, so the first term disappear completely?

So on the spin-manifold or the Pin$^-$-manifold, the $\mathbb{Z}_4$ class of $ \mathcal{P}(x)$ is reduced to a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ subclass generated by

> $$
> x \cup_1   Sq^1 x= \frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{P}(x) -x^2) ?
> $$
>   Is this precise?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. $w_i(M) \in H^i(M;\Bbb Z/2)$. It is not an element of the cohomology of $B\Bbb Z/2$.

Comment: sorry I had typoes let me fix it

Comment: I meant Pontryagin square, maps $x \in H^2({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ to $ \mathcal{P}(x) \in H^4({B}^2\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_4)$. I fix it, thanks - let me know your thoughts please

Comment: That doesn't seem to have been related to my comment. The Stiefel-Whitney classes of a manifold $M$ live in the cohomology of $M$, which never appears in your post.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean we can pair it with the fundamental classes of the manifold $M$. Agree?

Comment: I need to improve my notation, but the idea of pairing it with the fundamental classes of the manifold M shall work